# Check if number is in arithmetic progression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which there is a column of Order, Order column always increases in the order of 10 ie 10,20,30,40..... under the same parentId

Ie for Parent 1 The Order Column is 10,20,30,40 for Parent 2 the Order column can be 10,20

What I know is I have to use a logic that will run like 
n(R1+Rn)/2 
https://www.tiger-algebra.com/drill/10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100/

The database structure is as explained in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9557181f0c559131fa25bc5918b84bd4
There can be multiple DocumentId each documentId contain a bunch of DocumentData

Here DocumentDataId is The pk, a Parent Id is a self-referencing fk.

What I want to check is to ensure that the order is always in order ie 10,20,30,40 and not have duplicate or gaps like 10,20,20,40 How will I run this in SQL Server?

Comment: Is there another column that determines the order of order column? Something that tells that 10 is the first order for parentid, not 5th or last.

Comment: I want that 1st is 10,2nd is 20, 3rd  is 30...... I wanted to use a check constraint or somthing to ensure that this will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use windowed functions:

```
-- incorrect values
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
   FIRST_VALUE(OrderColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY Parent ORDER BY OrderColumn) +
   10*(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Parent ORDER BY OrderColumn)-1) AS progression
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE progression != OrderColumn;

-- correct
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
   FIRST_VALUE(OrderColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY Parent ORDER BY OrderColumn) +
   10*(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Parent ORDER BY OrderColumn)-1) AS progression
  FROM tab
)
SELECT Parent
FROM cte
EXCEPT
SELECT Parent
FROM cte
WHERE progression != OrderColumn
GROUP BY Parent;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6cd1879fd53a95aa067702151586b2f4)**

Comment: This fails when ParentId is null I tried PARTITION BY CASE WHEN ParentId IS NOT NULL THEN ParentId END, but does not work

Comment: @Anurag.Desai Please provide full representive sample of your data and desired resultset. Handling Nulls is not a problem, one way is to exclude them from query `WHERE Parent IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I have created a sql fiddle please check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9557181f0c559131fa25bc5918b84bd4 for the fiddle example Updated the question with the database explanation

Comment: @Anurag.Desai Option 1: Make column Parent as `NOT NULL` Option 2 with WHERE clause: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f1c39a4f5cee51f7eb18775237434fb)

Comment: Can we use the Partition by null in my case? http://my-oracle-10g-tips.blogspot.com/2008/07/partition-by-null.html

Comment: @Anurag.Desai I don't think so. `OVER(PARTITION BY column)` != `OVER(PARTITION BY null)` which is basically the same as you skipp `PARTITION BY` clause at all

Comment: I solved this issue by using https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5c54edd62fff160e94139faa3c8b92c9

Answer (score 0):

Based on the database structure I had to handle two situations when Parent is NULL and when Parent was not NULL

I used the code suggested by  @Lukasz Szozda and slightly changed it to include a container in my case was document and then Partitioned by It before the null case

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
   FIRST_VALUE(OrderColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentId,Parent ORDER BY OrderColumn) +
   10*(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentId,Parent ORDER BY OrderColumn)-1) AS ExpectedDisplayOrder
  FROM DocumentData
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE ExpectedDisplayOrder != OrderColumn;
```

Check the following fiddle for full extract
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5c54edd62fff160e94139faa3c8b92c9